# TypeError: fn got multiple values -- how to not pass self?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def b(arg1, kwarg1=None, kwarg2=None):
    print(arg1, kwarg1, kwarg2)


def c(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)


class A:
    fn = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.fn(1, kwarg1=2, kwarg2=3)


class B(A):
    fn = b


class C(A):
    fn = c


B()
C()
```

The idea is simple - there are a bunch of functions, eg `a`, `b` etc. Then there is a common behaviour to calling them, so I want to make a mixin for this. However, calling the variable that holds the function reference causes to also put `self` as the first argument. What's the best way to solve this pattern and/or how can I not put `self` as the first arg?

Answer (score 3):

One option is

```
class B(A):
    fn = staticmethod(b)
```

This wraps `b` so that if the call to `fn` is on an instance (`B().fn(...)`) the `self` (instance) argument is removed before the actual `b` is called.

**Another way which avoids modification of the subclasses** is to add a [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) method in `A`:

```
class A:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        fn = cls.__dict__.get("fn")
        if fn:
            cls.fn = staticmethod(fn)

    fn = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.fn(1, kwarg1=2, kwarg2=3)
```

This works since Python 3.6. For earlier version, a metaclass can be created instead. The special method is called when subclass is created and before its `__init__` is called. It replaces `fn` by the wrapped variant.

Comment: This indeed works, but it's very ugly which means my code is bad to begin with, there must be a better pattern for this problem?

Comment: @emihir0 I have added another variant which doesn't need to modify the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer works, just wanted to add some more explanation.

You have a couple options here, depending on what you want:

1. `staticmethod`. See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) for more details. It's usually used as a function decorator, but can also be called directly on a function to create a staticmethod for a class. A staticmethod does not receive a first argument. If you don't need to touch your class, or an instance of your class, in any of these functions, this is the best option.
2. `classmethod`. A class method is bound to the class, not to an instance of a class. You can call a class method from the class or from an instance of the class. [Python docs for classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod). If you need access to the class in your function, this is the option for you.
3. Change all the functions to have `self` as the first parameter. This is probably what you want to do if you're going to access instance variables or you need access to `self` in your functions.